# unable to retain the values for dynamic creation of grid rows after print

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have a gridview in which i have created dynamic rows in row created event as shown in below code.

```
protected void grdPBook_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
      strPreviousRowID = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.Date).ToString()}
      grdPBook.ShowFooter = false;
    }
}

protected void grdPBook_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    bool IsSubTotalRowNeedToAdd = false;
    bool IsGrandTotalRowNeedtoAdd = false;

    if (ddlSummary.SelectedValue == "0")
    {
      if ((strPreviousRowID != string.Empty)(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem,Date) != null))
      {
         if (strPreviousRowID != DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, Date).ToString())
         {
            if (ddlSummary.SelectedValue == "0")
            {
               IsSubTotalRowNeedToAdd = true;
            }
         }
      }

      if (IsSubTotalRowNeedToAdd)
      {
         // ---code for adding dynamic subtotal row-----
      }
    }
}
```

when i print the grid the print dialog opens and after closing the dialog the dynamically generated columns of grid disappers and the grid gets messed up coz i m not able to retain the values for Date(here)on the basis of which the dynamic rowsare generated.

How can i achieve the task.Help me.

Comment: Did you tried re-binding the grid after printing?

Comment: You have overcomplicated your solution a lot and it's hard to follow what you are trying to do. I dont understand the need to evaluate this expression twice in the same routine `ddlSummary.SelectedValue == "0"` or the need to hide the footer `grdPBook.ShowFooter = false` in `RowDataBound`. But I don't want to get into these details...can you show how you are bind your grid?

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void grdPBook_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
// your code
if (ddlSummary.SelectedValue == "0")
{
//your code
grdPBook.DataSource = dt;
//here dt is your Data Table object containing all rows.
}
grdPBook.DataBind();
}
```

Use grdPBook.DataBind(); in every Row operations.